# How to add month or year or day to the selected date in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
DateTime ct = DateTime.Now.Date;
            ct.AddMonths(5);
```

I am trying to get next 5th month from the current date. This code is not working for me.

Comment: Even though this is a easy to figure out question, saying "This code is not working" is not a good problem statement. Please say *what* isn't working and what you would *expect* it to do in the future.

Comment: When your code doesn't run as you expect it to, take the time to read the description of the method you are using. "Returns a **new DateTime** that adds the specified number of months to the value of this instance." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AddMonths` does not affect the original object, it returns a new object ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths(v=vs.110).aspx)).

You need to assign the result:

```
DateTime ct = DateTime.Now.Date;
DateTime future = ct.AddMonths(5);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
var ct = DateTime.Date.AddMonths(5)
```

Comment: Assuming they don't want `ct` for anything else, this is a much better line of code. It would be better to include ("This works because it acts on the `Date` value and returns a new `DateTime` to the `ct` variable") or some other explanation since the OP clearly doesn't understand this about the `AddMonths` function.

Comment: I agree, @BradleyDotNET.

Answer (score 2):

```
ct = ct.AddMonths(5);
```

it returns that date not adds to itself